# Compare two excel columns which the most frequently occur in specific date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, frequency-analysis

I would like to compare between few columns, what where the **top 5 most popular products in year 2015**.

I have this kind of data flow to work with:

```
Client | Product | Date of buy
------------------------------
client1 | A | 15.06.2015
client3 | A | 04.12.2015
client5 | F | 15.06.2015
client9 | G | 15.01.2015
client2 | G | 15.01.2015
client1 | R | 05.07.2015
client3 | G | 15.06.2015
client1 | F | 05.07.2015
client3 | F | 15.06.2016
```

Results - which products client bought the most with (in same date) the top 5 products communities of them. E.g..

```
 1. Product A + Product H 222 times
 2. Product A + Product E 77 times
 3. Product B + Product O 70 times
 4. etc
 5. ...
```

Greetz,

Comment: Use a pivot table?

Comment: your date format is inconsistant.  unless we now have 15 months.  You have 15 for both the first number and for the second number. (See client 9 and 2)

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, that's a typo. its DD/MM/YYYY format actually and i don't know how to use that pivot table.

Comment: How do you plan on dealing with ties?  right now your criteria results in G - 3 times, A - 2 times and F - 2 times.  What would the top ttwo most frequent items be?  Are we allowed to use helper columns?

Comment: I changed the result idea a bit in the post.. Thanks!

Comment: The idea may have change a bit, but it can change how things are done, and invalidate previous answer.  See [Russian Doll Q&A](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625/etiquette-for-russian-doll-questions). It is better to ask a new question and link it to this question and state it is a follow up question.  edit this post and copy it, cancel out and ask a new question and paste your question in. When the new question is up come back to this one and edit it back to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption:

1. you can use helper columns.
2. Your Columns up above are A, B and C.
3. You have two header rows and data starts in row 3.
4. Your dates are stored in an excel date format and not string values.

In E2 I generated a list of unique product items using the following formula:

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$11,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($E$2:E2,$B$3:$B$11),0,0),0))
```

I copied it down to match the number of rows in the initial list.  It starts spitting #N/A when all the unique items in the list have been listed.  If you want to avoid this you could put the formula inside of:

```
=IFERROR(insert formula,"")
```

Now in column F I did a count based on your criteria of each item and within the year 2015. I used a multiple count if function called COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$11,"<"&DATE(2016,1,1),
          $C$3:$C$11,">"&DATE(2014,12,31),
          $B$3:$B$11,E3)
```

I just reformatted that for easier reading.  You will have to edit that slightly if you want to copy and paste.  If you don't like seeing 0 when there is no product in the adjacent column you could wrap the equation in:

```
=IF(E3="","",  insert formula  )
```

I then skipped a column and sorted the list of counted items from largest to smallest and had it return the numbers in sequence.  I only went down two rows, but you could technically do the whole list.  The large function does this and the formula in H3 looks like:

```
=LARGE($F$3:$F$11,ROWS($1:1))
```

I then went back 1 column and put the product name that corresponds to the count, and then took the next name in the list when products had equal count.  I put that in column F as normally when I read I want to read the product name first then read the quantity. If you want it the other way around just swap the columns.  The formula in G1 is:

```
=INDEX($E$3:$E$11,MATCH(H3,$F$3:$F$11,0)+COUNTIF($H$3:$H3,H3)-1)
```

Copy E3 and F3 down as far as you need.  Copy G3 and H3 down one row and you will have top two.  down two rows and you have top three etc.

This is how it looks...The dates are displayed according to my computers date format.

[image: Results]